# $E(x^k)$ under a Gaussian

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value

What would be the expectation of $|x|^k$, where $x\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$, $k>0$ and $k$ is not an integer?

Comment: This reads like standard bookwork for a basic subject on distributions. Is this for some subject?

Comment: I think youneed to use absolute value, as non-integer power don't make sense for negative numbers.  Or are you intending to get an answer in the complex domain?

Comment: @Glen_b it's for my PhD. I've oversimplified the actual problem that I have

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$E(x^k)$ can be worked out directly from the law of the unconscious statistician

$E(x^k) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x^k \phi(x) dx$ where $\phi$ is the standard normal pdf

You may be able to make progress with a simple substitution.

See also:

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalDistribution.html (this gives the numeric answers)

and

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GaussianIntegral.html

---

Responding to the updated question: we just follow my suggestion above (simple substitution).

\begin{eqnarray}
E(|x|^k) &=& \int_{-\infty}^\infty |x|^k \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/2}dx\\
         &=& 2\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{0}^\infty x^k e^{-x^2/2}dx
\end{eqnarray}

Let $u = x^2/2;\,$ so $ du  = x\,dx;\,x=(2u)^{1/2}$

\begin{eqnarray}
   &=& 2\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{0}^\infty (2u)^{\frac{k-1}{2}} e^{-u}du\\
   &=& \frac{2^{k/2}}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_{0}^\infty u^{\frac{k-1}{2}} e^{-u}du\\
   &=& \frac{2^{k/2}}{\sqrt{\pi}} \Gamma\left(\frac{k+1}{2}\right)
\end{eqnarray}

In fact the second link above shows you how to it for the non-integer case - see eqns (9)-(12); there's nothing there requiring the power to be an integer.

Comment: All the answers given are in the case when k is an integer. I'm afraid I need it for the non-integer case

Comment: (+1) The Gamma function is defined for all *complex* numbers except the non-positive integers, so this solution certainly works for positive non-integral reals.  However--a little nit-pick--the calculations done here are meaningless until one changes $|x^k|$ to $|x|^k$ or else makes some assumptions about branches of the complex logarithm. :-)

Comment: @whuber Thanks, that's a typo - it's meant to be as in the current question; fixed.