# $E(x^k)$ under truncated $\mathcal{N}(\mu,1)$

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value, integral, truncation

There is a similar question in [$E(x^k)$ under a Gaussian](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/74833/exk-under-a-gaussian?noredirect=1#comment145996_74833). However, it doesn't seem to be trivial when $\mu\ne0$. As mentioned in the previous question **$k$ is not an integer**.

The integral that I need to evaluate is as follows:
$$\int_0^\infty x^k\exp\left(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2}\right)dx$$

If it helps for the case that $\mu=0$ the answer is $\frac{2^{(k-2)/2}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\Gamma(\frac{k+1}{2})$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a Mellin transform. In general notation we have ($a>0, s>0$)

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{s-1}\exp\left\{-ax^2-bx\right\}dx = (2a)^{-1/2}\Gamma(s)\exp\left\{\frac {b^2}{8a}\right\}D_{-s}\left(b(2a)^{-1/2}\right)$$

where $D_{-s}()$ is (Whittaker's) parabolic cylinder function.

For your integral we have

$$I=\int_0^\infty x^k\exp\left\{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2}\right\}dx = \exp\left\{\frac {-\mu^2}{2}\right\}\int_0^\infty x^k\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2} +\mu x\right)dx  $$

Matching coefficients we get

$$s-1 = k \Rightarrow s=k+1,\;\; a=\frac 12,\;\; b=-\mu$$

Inserting into the general solution we have

$$I=\exp\left\{\frac {-\mu^2}{2}\right\}\left(2\frac 12\right)^{-1/2}\Gamma(k+1)\exp\left\{\frac {\mu^2}{8\frac 12}\right\}D_{-k-1}\left(-\mu\left(2\frac 12\right)^{-1/2}\right)$$

$$=\exp\left\{\frac {-\mu^2}{4}\right\}\Gamma(k+1)D_{-k-1}\left(-\mu\right)$$

Now set $k^* =k +\frac 12$. Then $D_{-k-1}\left(-\mu\right) = D_{-k^*-\frac 12}\left(-\mu\right)$ and for the second you can look up Abramowitz and Stegun [p.687](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_687.htm) and 686, starting with eq. $19.3.1$. You will indeed see that when $\mu\neq 0$ the situation is not trivial. The fact that $k$ is not an integer causes no special trouble.

Comment: Does the parabolic cylinder function have any relation to any of the bessel functions?

Comment: @Sachin_ruk Whittaker's parabolic cylinder function $D()$ is connected to the "modern" $U()$ and $V()$ par.cyl. functions which in turn have some connections with modified Bessels (see ref. in my answer and also a few pages later, http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_692.htm ).